# Why does my even and odd printing program print just print odd many times?

Tags: java, printing

I'm trying to make a java program that takes a number given by the user, and displays whether it is odd or even. I am having trouble, i think it might be tht my logic is wrong idk. It just prints the never ending  message "odd"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questions {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Your number");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i = +2)
      if (number == i) {
        System.out.println("even");
      } else {
        System.out.println("odd");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The modulo operator. You need it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an endless `for` statement, because you don't change a loop variable `i`. You might try the following pieces of code to decide your task:

```
System.out.println(number % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
```

or

```
System.out.println((number & 1) == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
```

Those lines will give same result:

```
(number = 2)
even
```

---

Of course, in your case, you might change this line `for (int i = 0; i <= number; i = +2)` to the next line `for (int i = 0; i <= number; i += 2)`, but an output won't give an expected result:

```
(number = 2)
odd
even
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you have the assignement

```
i =+ 2
```

This sets the variable `i` to positive 2.
To add 2 to the variable use:

```
i += 2
```

This would print "odd" as long as `i` is smaller than the input value and print a final "even" if the value is event or "odd" if the value is odd.

Btw to test if a value is a multiple of another value you can use

```
if ((value % otherValue) == 0) {}
```

so in your example

```
if ((number % 2) == 0) {
    System.out.println("even");
} else {
    System.out.println("odd");
}
```

or even shorter

```
System.out.println((number % 2) == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your check for an odd / even number is wrong and could be optimised. Use the modulus operator instead:

```
if (number % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Even");
} else {
    System.out.println("Odd");
}
```

The modulus gives you the remainder of the division of the operands. If you divide by 2 and the remainder is 0 - you have an even number.

Answer (score 1):

you are make mistake in the for statement

```
for (int i = 0; i <= number; i = +2)// this will not increment the counter, it will set it every time with  2 positive

for (int i = 0; i <= number; i +=2)// this will increment the counter by 2 in every iteration
```

also you should try to find the problem by debugging or use some print statements after loop or in condition to troubleshot this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This program never terminates.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= number; i=+2)
```

The offending code is that last item. Incrementing i by 2 looks like this:

```
i += 2;
```

If you write it like this:

```
i =+ 2;
```

Then it will just repeatedly assign the value '2' to i.

Of course, as the other posters already pointed out, this isn't how you should test evenness/oddness. You should either perform a modulo check:

```
if(i % 2 == ) <even>
else <odd>
```

Or simply perform a bitwise comparison on the last digit.

```
if(i & 1 == 0) <even>
else <odd>
```